# How to add values to the array using 3 select queries in sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, random

There is a question pool.question pool table name is 'question'

```
question{
    question_id PRIMARY KEY,
    question,
    option1,
    option2,
    option3,
    option4,
    level_id FOREIGN KEY,
    category_id FOREIGN KEY
}

exam_paper{
    exam_paper_id,
    exam_paper_name,
    level_1_no_of_questions,
    level_2_no_of_questions,
    level_3_no_of_questions
}
exam_paper_questions{
    id PRIMARY KEY,
    exam_paper_id FOREIGN KEY,
    q0,
    q1,
    q2,
    q3,
    q4,
    q5,
    q6,
    q7,
    q8,
    q9
}
```

there are 10 questions in the question paper. there are 3 levels of questions like easy, intermediate and difficult. I want to add 3 questions from easy level(level 1), 4 questions from intermediate level(level 2) and 3 questions from difficult level(level 3) randomly selected from the question pool into the exam paper. 
How to write the query? and how to insert to the questions to paper?

Comment: This looks like homework. Also it looks like you are asking us to write code without even attempting to do it first. Do not expect any replies, answers nor suggestions. If you need help debugging something (which is what SO is designed for) we will assist you, but if you need actual code written hire a freelancer.

Comment: I get the data using select query.